# How can I validate an illegal offset warning?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
      dump($value);
    }
```

With a dump of my loop I get this output:

```
array:2 [▼
  "id" => "9a989408e5"
  "Name" => "cat"
]


array:2 [▼
  "id" => "47601aae85"
  "Name" => "elephant"
]


array:2 [▼
  "uuid" => "7cb16ddafc"
  "Anzahl" => "rabbit"
]
```

But if I try to catch only the id....

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
      dump($value['id']);
    }
```

I get the error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'id'

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Can you share more details such that others could reproduce the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase problem was solved by `if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)){`

Comment: ....solved? That code does not check whether the array key `id` exists after all

Comment: @NicoHaase Hmmm. But I do not get the error message anymore. That is why I thought it is solved

Comment: You haven't checked what `$value` really contains?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
 foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)){
       dump($value['id']);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This code doesn't check if **id** key exists in the array

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if this key exists in the array using **array_key_exists()**. Like this:

```
if(array_key_exists('id', $value)){
    dump($value['id']);
}
```

Comment: that does not work. I get the error `Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given`

Comment: I assume you do the **if** check within the `foreach` loop? Based on your dump output this shouldn't happen. However, you can combine your own reply with the `array_key_exists`. First, check if it is an array. Then, check if the array has key **id**.